# Javascript concatenate two variables with "--"

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to concatenate two variables. When i'm using alert getting this error message [object HTMLInputElement]--[object HTMLInputElement].

```
    var Name = document.getElementById("thevoornaam");
    var DoB = document.getElementById("thedate");

    var catVar = Name + "--" + DoB;
    alert(catVar);
```

Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: You need to read value from the element. Just add `.value` to the end of the first two statements.

Comment: make it `Name.value + "--" + DoB.value;`

Comment: Don't capitalise those variable names.  Variables are always `camelCase` unless they're a constructior function, in which case they can be `PascalCase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to fetch the value by using [.value](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp)

```
    var Name = document.getElementById("thevoornaam").value;
    var DoB = document.getElementById("thedate").value;

    var catVar = Name + "--" + DoB;
    alert(catVar);
```

Comment: you should explain, not only correct. A simple sentence like : "If you want to concatenate the value inside those dom elements do that" would do the job.

Comment: @hezanathos i have explained it

Comment: yeah you editied, thats a little better. You still are not really explaning.

Comment: Thanks @Ghostman :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function (){

  var Name = document.getElementById("thevoornaam").innerHTML ;
  var DoB = document.getElementById("thedate").innerHTML ;

  var catVar = Name + "--" + DoB;

 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML  = catVar;

};
```

```html
v1: <span id="thevoornaam">Name</span> <br />
v2: <span id="thedate">DoB</span>
<hr />
r: <span id="result"></span>
```